# Is there a formal definition of when an algorithm is greedy?

Tags: algorithms, definition

I have checked the question, [Definition of a Greedy Algorithm](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1618627/definition-of-a-greedy-algorithm), but there was no formal definition of a greedy algorithm. I want to know, is there a formal definition of an algorithm that is greedy? Or is this a notion which is not amenable to formalization?

Comment: Interesting question.  To me a "greedy" algorithm is one that just grabs the biggest possible eligible object of the type under consideration.  Granted, there are lots of undefined, or at least unquantified,  terms in that sentence.

Comment: It seems to me that your question is already answered in that thread, whose accepted answer, repeating a point already made in comments, states that "greedy" is a fuzzy concept, not some formal description. An algorithm is greedy if it always takes the maximum in certain places where a choice is available.